# Animation nodes nested loops

Tags: python, animation, animation-nodes

I would like to replicate the following python code in animation nodes:

```
a = [1,2,3]
c = []

for i in a:
    for k in a:
        c.append(i*k)
print(c)
```

The output is [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9].

However in animation nodes I can not make this work. Below is my current nodes setup:
[image]
(I know that this could be done in AN in a simpler way however I need something like this for a more complicated project.)

Comment: Duplicate? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130932/combine-all-lists-from-nested-subprogramm-animation-nodes    https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=nested+loops+%5Banimation-nodes%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a simple case, like in your question, you can also use *"expression"* node and avoid nested loops.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

[image]